# Successive calculation from one row to the next possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a selection with rows for several process steps, which my material (paper) is running through in our printing company.
In each of the process steps material is lost due to handling and mistakes. The estimated loss is available as a percentage value for each row.
I would like to have such an output:

| process step | material at the start | loss in % | material at the end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 10 | 900 |
| 2 | 900 | 15 | 765 |
| 3 | 765 | 12 | 673 |

What I have are the process steps, the loss in % and the amount of material at the start of process step 1. Obviously I can calculate the remaining material after step 1, but I can't find a way to get this value to the row of step 2 to continue the calculation.

Comment: have you consider LEAD() or LAG() ? Also. you should add the version of SQL server.

Comment: You usually need to use a recursive CTE query for these kind of calculations, examples on how to do it are plenty abound

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to use recursion here. As your table has not process ID then I *assume* that they are all part of the same process. This is unlikely to be true in the real world, so (presumably) you will need to change the `ON` clause to be correct for your real data.

Anyway, you can use an rCTE iterate through the data and apply the percentage loss to the prior end material. Note that if you have a process with more than 100 steps this will fail, and you'll need to add an `OPTION` clause to increase the `MAXRECURSION` value. If you have circular references, then you have a bigger problem (and you probably need to address that).

Anyway, this gives you a solution like so:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.MyTable
     --Derived table for "sane" names
FROM (SELECT V.[process step] AS ProcessStep,
                 V.[material at the start] AS StartMaterial,
                 V.[loss in %] AS PercentageLoss,
                 V.[material at the end] AS EndMaterial
          FROM (VALUES(1,1000,10,900),
                      (2,900,15,765),
                      (3,765,12,673))V([process step],[material at the start],[loss in %],[material at the end]))YT;
GO

WITH rCTE AS (
    SELECT MT.ProcessStep,
           CONVERT(decimal(10,0),MT.StartMaterial) AS StartMaterial,
           MT.PercentageLoss,
           CONVERT(decimal(10,0),MT.StartMaterial - (MT.StartMaterial * (MT.PercentageLoss/100.))) AS EndMaterial
    FROM dbo.MyTable MT
    WHERE MT.ProcessStep = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MT.ProcessStep,
           CONVERT(decimal(10,0),r.EndMaterial) AS StartMaterial,
           MT.PercentageLoss,
           CONVERT(decimal(10,0),r.EndMaterial - (r.EndMaterial * (MT.PercentageLoss/100.))) AS EndMaterial
    FROM dbo.MyTable MT
         JOIN rCTE r ON MT.ProcessStep = r.ProcessStep + 1)
SELECT rCTE.ProcessStep,
       rCTE.StartMaterial,
       rCTE.PercentageLoss,
       rCTE.EndMaterial
FROM rCTE;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable
```